Pspice simulation not working
I am simulating the evaluation board LM5145EVM-HD-20A on Pspice.
(https://www.ti.com/tool/LM5145EVM-HD-20A)
LM5145 already has the Pspice model for the same but the switches used are not Pspice models of the mosfets in the simulation as you can see in the image below. The simulation works.

But when I add the actual Pspice models of the MOSFETS as shown below, the simulation is not working and the error is coming as : There are no data values in section number 1 ignoring this section and it stops.

Error that the output window is showing :

Please provide any solution.

Try using a different MOSFET and see if those errors remain. If the errors go away then you've narrowed the problem down to the model file of the MOSFET. Divide and conquer.
